# Running into errors trying to get rails to work on my Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

EDIT- Solved it, For those running into the same error.
Make sure this is what you have in your .zshrc file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then run, `source ~/.zshrc` , Then uninstall the ruby version with rbenv you are trying to set global and install it again and try setting it to global again. Then uninstall rails, if it says rails isn't installed, Install rails and everything should run :)

---

I recently bought the MacBook Pro 16 as my first Mac ever, its been hell ever since trying to get rails to work.

*Note*, command line tools are already installed..

**ruby -v** `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]` ( Unable to change global ruby version using rbenv for some reason..... )

**rails -v**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    1: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
/Users/taha/odin_on_rails/my_first_rails_app/bin/spring:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `specs' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

running `rails g scaffold car make:string model:string year:integer` gives out the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    1: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
/Users/Matthew/odin_on_rails/my_first_rails_app/bin/spring:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `specs' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Following previous stack overflow solutions I found that prepending `bundle exec` to the above command should work, however it didn't and this was the error report it outputted.

**ERROR REPORT**-> https://pastebin.com/KkzMKNic

Also tried `bin/rails generate scaffold car make:string model:string year:integer` to see if that may work, no luck there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    1: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
/Users/Matthew/odin_on_rails/my_first_rails_app/bin/spring:5:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `specs' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Also, for some reason rbenv global returns the default system version of ruby that comes with MacOS despite me changing it to 2.7.0 and following several stack overflow solutions.

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer instead of editing your question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The same error just happened here during `rails new`. I do not have a MAC, neither zsh nor rbenv. My installation works well for ruby 2.6 + rails 6.0.3; it did not work for ruby 2.7 + rails 6.1.1.

The reason is because rails now by default installs spring, and spring expects an established bundle to work. spring invokes `Bundler.locked_gems.specs`, and here the `Bundler.locked_gems` is `nil`, which leads to the error.

In my case the reason is because I intentionally run `rails new APP --skip-bundle` - so there will be no bundle.
The workaround then is to also add `--skip-spring`. Spring can be installed later.

But in the case of the OP this error rather points to some flaw in the system's configuration, leading to the bundle not being set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common miss when installing ROR with rbenv. Better to follow to this guide while installing ruby on rails on a new mac.

[ROR installation guide for mac](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-macos)